# ant script to build ejb project and deploy on Weblogic

Tags: ant, ejb, weblogic12c

I have an Ejb(3.1) project which i want to build and deploy on Weblogic 12c using ant build file.
I am able to create a ejb-jar file and It is getting deployed on Weblogic but when I click on the deployed ejb-jar file from eclipse console to double check the deployment, following error message is displayed:
Please help.

```
 <Error> <Console> <WGC1W7JKCR65J> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <6511265e550b6034:-4d6743a3:14e8c70b04f:-8000-000000000000001c> <1436880971372> <BEA-240003> <Administration Console encountered the following error: java.io.IOException: Exception in AppMerge flows' progression
at weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.getMergedApp(AppMerger.java:63)
at weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:181)
at weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:163)
at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.initialize(SessionHelper.java:727)
at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.initializeConfiguration(SessionHelper.java:556)
at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.initializeConfiguration(SessionHelper.java:544)
at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.initializeConfiguration(SessionHelper.java:627)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationHelper$1.execute(DeploymentConfigurationHelper.java:858)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentUtils.runDeploymentAction(DeploymentUtils.java:5035)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationHelper.initDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationHelper.java:847)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationHelper.completeInitialization(DeploymentConfigurationHelper.java:443)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationManager.getDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationManager.java:150)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationManager.getDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationManager.java:104)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationManager.getDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationManager.java:65)
at com.bea.console.utils.PersistenceUtils.getPersistenceUnitNames(PersistenceUtils.java:76)
at com.bea.console.utils.PersistenceUtils.hasPersistenceUnits(PersistenceUtils.java:52)
at com.bea.console.utils.AppDeploymentBackingFile.preRender(AppDeploymentBackingFile.java:110)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.Backable$Impl.preRender(Backable.java:191)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.AdministeredBackableControl.preRender(AdministeredBackableControl.java:104)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.window.Window.preRender(Window.java:445)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.page.Page.preRender(Page.java:239)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlLifecycle$6.visit(ControlLifecycle.java:428)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:727)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walk(ControlTreeWalker.java:146)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:399)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:361)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.runOutbound(Lifecycle.java:208)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.run(Lifecycle.java:162)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.runLifecycle(UIServlet.java:465)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doPost(UIServlet.java:291)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doGet(UIServlet.java:231)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.service(UIServlet.java:216)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.SingleFileServlet.service(SingleFileServlet.java:275)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.service(MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.java:64)
at weblogic.servlet.AsyncInitServlet.service(AsyncInitServlet.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:242)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:216)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:132)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:352)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:74)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:74)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3288)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3254)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2163)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2089)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2074)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1512)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)    Caused by: weblogic.utils.compiler.ToolFailureException: Exception in AppMerge flows' progression
at weblogic.application.compiler.AppMerge.merge(AppMerge.java:176)
at weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.merge(AppMerger.java:81)
at weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.getMergedApp(AppMerger.java:56)
at weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:181)
at weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:163)
at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.initialize(SessionHelper.java:727)
at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.initializeConfiguration(SessionHelper.java:557)
at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.initializeConfiguration(SessionHelper.java:545)
at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.initializeConfiguration(SessionHelper.java:628)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationHelper$1.execute(DeploymentConfigurationHelper.java:860)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentUtils.runDeploymentAction(DeploymentUtils.java:5035)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationHelper.initDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationHelper.java:847)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationHelper.completeInitialization(DeploymentConfigurationHelper.java:443)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationManager.getDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationManager.java:150)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationManager.getDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationManager.java:105)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationManager.getDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationManager.java:65)
at com.bea.console.utils.PersistenceUtils.getPersistenceUnitNames(PersistenceUtils.java:76)
at com.bea.console.utils.PersistenceUtils.hasPersistenceUnits(PersistenceUtils.java:52)
at com.bea.console.utils.AppDeploymentBackingFile.preRender(AppDeploymentBackingFile.java:110)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.Backable$Impl.preRender(Backable.java:191)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.AdministeredBackableControl.preRender(AdministeredBackableControl.java:104)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.window.Window.preRender(Window.java:445)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.page.Page.preRender(Page.java:248)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlLifecycle$6.visit(ControlLifecycle.java:429)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:727)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walk(ControlTreeWalker.java:146)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:399)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:361)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.runOutbound(Lifecycle.java:208)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.run(Lifecycle.java:162)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.runLifecycle(UIServlet.java:466)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doPost(UIServlet.java:291)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doGet(UIServlet.java:232)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.service(UIServlet.java:216)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.SingleFileServlet.service(SingleFileServlet.java:277)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:845)
at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.service(MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.java:64)
at weblogic.servlet.AsyncInitServlet.service(AsyncInitServlet.java:126)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:242)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:216)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:132)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:352)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:75)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:75)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3288)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3254)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2163)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2091)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2074)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1512)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
... 2 more    Caused by: weblogic.utils.compiler.ToolFailureException: Unable to find a suitable factory among registered factories
at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.handleStateChangeException(FlowDriver.java:54)
at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:38)
at weblogic.application.compiler.AppMerge.runBody(AppMerge.java:159)
at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:158)
at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:115)
at weblogic.application.compiler.AppMerge.merge(AppMerge.java:173)
at weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.merge(AppMerger.java:81)
at weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.getMergedApp(AppMerger.java:56)
at weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:181)
at weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:163)
at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.initialize(SessionHelper.java:727)
at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.initializeConfiguration(SessionHelper.java:556)
at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.initializeConfiguration(SessionHelper.java:544)
at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.initializeConfiguration(SessionHelper.java:627)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationHelper$1.execute(DeploymentConfigurationHelper.java:858)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentUtils.runDeploymentAction(DeploymentUtils.java:5035)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationHelper.initDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationHelper.java:847)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationHelper.completeInitialization(DeploymentConfigurationHelper.java:443)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationManager.getDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationManager.java:150)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationManager.getDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationManager.java:104)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationManager.getDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationManager.java:65)
at com.bea.console.utils.PersistenceUtils.getPersistenceUnitNames(PersistenceUtils.java:76)
at com.bea.console.utils.PersistenceUtils.hasPersistenceUnits(PersistenceUtils.java:52)
at com.bea.console.utils.AppDeploymentBackingFile.preRender(AppDeploymentBackingFile.java:110)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.Backable$Impl.preRender(Backable.java:191)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.AdministeredBackableControl.preRender(AdministeredBackableControl.java:104)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.window.Window.preRender(Window.java:445)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.page.Page.preRender(Page.java:239)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlLifecycle$6.visit(ControlLifecycle.java:428)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:727)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walk(ControlTreeWalker.java:146)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:399)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:361)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.runOutbound(Lifecycle.java:208)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.run(Lifecycle.java:162)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.runLifecycle(UIServlet.java:465)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doPost(UIServlet.java:291)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doGet(UIServlet.java:231)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.service(UIServlet.java:216)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.SingleFileServlet.service(SingleFileServlet.java:275)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.service(MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.java:64)
at weblogic.servlet.AsyncInitServlet.service(AsyncInitServlet.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:242)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:216)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:132)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:352)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:74)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:74)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3288)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3254)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2163)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2089)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2074)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1512)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
... 2 more Caused by: weblogic.application.compiler.NoClaimsFactoryException: Unable to find a suitable factory among registered factories
at weblogic.application.compiler.FactoryManager.create(FactoryManager.java:110)
at weblogic.application.compiler.ToolsFactoryManager.createStandaloneModule(ToolsFactoryManager.java:118)
at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.SingleModuleFlow.compile(SingleModuleFlow.java:40)
at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$FlowStateChange.next(FlowDriver.java:71)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:37)
at weblogic.application.compiler.BaseMerger.merge(BaseMerger.java:21)
at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.AppMergerFlow.mergeInput(AppMergerFlow.java:75)
at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.AppMergerFlow.compile(AppMergerFlow.java:41)
at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$FlowStateChange.next(FlowDriver.java:71)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:37)
at weblogic.application.compiler.AppMerge.runBody(AppMerge.java:159)
at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:158)
at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:116)
at weblogic.application.compiler.AppMerge.merge(AppMerge.java:174)
at weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.merge(AppMerger.java:81)
at weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.getMergedApp(AppMerger.java:56)
at weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:181)
at weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:163)
at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.initialize(SessionHelper.java:727)
at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.initializeConfiguration(SessionHelper.java:557)
at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.initializeConfiguration(SessionHelper.java:545)
at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.initializeConfiguration(SessionHelper.java:628)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationHelper$1.execute(DeploymentConfigurationHelper.java:860)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentUtils.runDeploymentAction(DeploymentUtils.java:5035)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationHelper.initDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationHelper.java:847)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationHelper.completeInitialization(DeploymentConfigurationHelper.java:443)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationManager.getDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationManager.java:150)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationManager.getDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationManager.java:105)
at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentConfigurationManager.getDeploymentConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationManager.java:65)
at com.bea.console.utils.PersistenceUtils.getPersistenceUnitNames(PersistenceUtils.java:76)
at com.bea.console.utils.PersistenceUtils.hasPersistenceUnits(PersistenceUtils.java:52)
at com.bea.console.utils.AppDeploymentBackingFile.preRender(AppDeploymentBackingFile.java:110)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.Backable$Impl.preRender(Backable.java:191)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.AdministeredBackableControl.preRender(AdministeredBackableControl.java:104)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.window.Window.preRender(Window.java:445)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.page.Page.preRender(Page.java:248)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlLifecycle$6.visit(ControlLifecycle.java:429)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:727)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursivePreRender(ControlTreeWalker.java:739)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walk(ControlTreeWalker.java:146)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:399)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:361)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.runOutbound(Lifecycle.java:208)
at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.run(Lifecycle.java:162)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.runLifecycle(UIServlet.java:466)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doPost(UIServlet.java:291)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doGet(UIServlet.java:232)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.service(UIServlet.java:216)
at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.SingleFileServlet.service(SingleFileServlet.java:277)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:845)
at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.service(MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.java:64)
at weblogic.servlet.AsyncInitServlet.service(AsyncInitServlet.java:126)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:242)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:216)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:132)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:352)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:75)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:75)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3288)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3254)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2163)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2091)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2074)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1512)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
```

Comment: The interesting error is `NoClaimsFactoryException: Unable to find a suitable factory among registered factories`. Are you sure you've built against the correct weblogic libraries? That error literally only has one other google result...

Comment: I am using weblogic system libraries from weblogic home, also JDK is 1.7_45.  I observed in this link about sme issues in Weblogic 12.1.1 [link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3597681)  I am using the same server and unfortunately unable to upgrade because of Company policy. Is there a workaround to it?